# How to make this page responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive, adobe-xd

I have a background image ([LINK 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qaU-XPBfebUwTNhmdMw350zQ2amkb4Dk/view?usp=sharing), [LINK 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl39O.png)) exported from Adobe XD. The image is over 9k pixels in height.
Since it's my first time working on Adobe XD files, I don't know to make this page responsive.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS :

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: grid;
    height: 9289px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 40px;
    background-image: url('Home.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Please could you explain what you want the resulting background to look like. Do you really want the body to be that high or do you want the background to somehow adjust to a body width/height of the viewport - for example so that the first part that has some different 'content' from the repeated wavy bits is seen. Or do you want all the repeated wavy bits squashed up so they fit in the viewport? You are already using cover which would be the normal recommendation, but on a hugely high body.

Answer (score 0):

changing the background-size to contain  should help.

If the background-size property is set to "contain", the background image will scale, and try to fit the content area. However, the image will keep its aspect ratio (the proportional relationship between the image's width and height):